# Не запускается jar файл JavaFX проекта intelliJIDEA

Tags: java, javafx, jar, build

Сделал готовый javaFX проект intellijIDEA.
Зашел ProjectStructure -> Artifacts -> Add jar

Поставил main class и включил, использующиеся библиотеки.

Применил нажал Build Artifacts -> Build Successful Получился jar файл, но при открытии его в консоли выдаёт ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

sample.Main.Main.start(Main.java:24) - это FXMLloader

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/main.fxml"));
```

Смотрел в jar файле, директории, которые стояли остались fxml файл есть, но не загружает.

Comment: А вы уверены, что запрашиваемый файл существует?

Comment: Я же написал, что проверил в jar файле его и снова щас перепроверил, может я путь как-то неправильно указал. Просто в самой IDEA проект запускается

Comment: Может java не нравится, что я даю ему относительный путь. Просто тогда если я укажу абсолютный это не будет работать на других компьютерах.

Comment: Попробуйте настроить маппинг от корня  / . В jar точка отсчета другая против несобранного проекта

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, проблема была всё таки в путях, вместо ../fxml/main.fxml
использовал /sample/fxml/main.fxml т.е дал путь от основной папки проекта и всё заработало.
Может кому-то поможет, а может я один такой тугой)

Comment: Спасибо! Была та же проблема, твой комментарий реально помог.
Исправил пути к fxml файлам и все поднялось.Так что нас таких тугих как минимум двое)